# HY:093 Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I dont understand why I'm getting this error

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require "../config.php";
    require "../common.php";
    try  {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $new_user = array(
            "Nom"  => $_POST['Nom'],
            "EmailID"     => $_POST['EmailID'],

            "localité"  => $_POST['localité']
        );
        $sql = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
                "memfis",
                implode(", ", array_keys($new_user)),
                ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_user))
        );

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($new_user);
    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
}
?>

<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) { ?>
    <blockquote><?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> successfully added.</blockquote>
<?php } ?>
```

Should Only had added the user and display "'Nom' successfully added" and Nom should and the other fields should have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complex on the query build? It is typically better to be readable and maintainable than fancy.

```
$sql = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
        "memfis",
        implode(", ", array_keys($new_user)),
        ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_user))
);
```

Maybe try changing that to something like:

```
$table = "memfis";
$columnNames = implode(", ", array_keys($new_user));
$columnPlaceholders = ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_user));
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columnNames) VALUES ($columnPlaceholders)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

And then because your query is going to have things like `:Nom` as placeholders, you need to use `bindParam()`.

```
foreach (array_keys($new_user) as $key) {
    $placeholder = ":" . $key;
    $stmt->bindParam($placeholder, $new_user[$key]);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

I know that code is longer, but it is easier to read and maintain IMHO than what you have.

Comment: This time I get a blank page and the row has still not been added

Comment: Do a `var_dump($sql); exit;` before the prepare statement.

Comment: string(80) "INSERT INTO memfis (Nom, EmailID, localité) VALUES (:Nom, :EmailID, :localité)"
I have this now
Row still not added

Comment: @JeremyHarris when you try to do a foreach on `$columnNames` it's a string, not an array. You should do a foreach on `array_keys($new_user)` instead.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks Nick.